# how to programmaticaly change div position in html using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

A parent `div` contains multiple `div`s, one `div` named `.div_object_last` should always be at the end. Like the example below :

**HTML**

```
<div class="div_parent">
    <div class="div_object">1</div>
    <div class="div_object">2</div>
    <div class="div_object_last"></div>
    <div class="div_object">3</div> <!--- append -->
</div>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$('#div_parent').append('<div class="div_object">3</div>');
```

---

**Expected result using JS :**

```
<div class="div_parent">
    <div class="div_object">1</div>
    <div class="div_object">2</div>
    <div class="div_object">3</div> 
    <div class="div_object_last"></div> <!--- moved to end --->
</div>
```

I was wondering if it was possible to put `div_object_last` at the end after the append event ?

Comment: You can use .before()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the `.div_object_last` and use `before()` to add the new content:

```js
$('.div_parent .div_object_last').before('<div class="div_object">3</div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_parent">
  <div class="div_object">1</div>
  <div class="div_object">2</div>
  <div class="div_object_last">Last</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To insert an element before the last child element:

```
$('.div_parent').children().last().before('<div class="div_object">3</div>');
```

To move an existing element to be the last:

```
$('.div_object_last').appendTo('.div_parent');
```

To move `el1` above/below `el2`:

```
// Above
$(el1).before(el2);

// Below
$(el1).after(el2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this dynamic way :

```
$('.div_parent').append($('.div_parent .div_object_last'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.div_parent div:last').before('<div class="div_object">3</div>');

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="div_parent">
   <div class="div_object">1</div>
   <div class="div_object">2</div>
   <div class="div_object_last">Last</div>
 </div>
```